# Passing RoR app user registration through JavaScript

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I am trying to give user the ability to register for my site via a page other than the registration page. I'm doing this through some simple JQuery that shows the form. The code is working perfectly on localhost, but as soon as I move it to production, it works only 5% or less of the time.

Relevant Code:

**The form part:**

```
<%= simple_form_for(User.new, :url => user_registration_path, :remote => true) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :first_name %>
  <%= f.input :last_name %>
  <%= f.input :email, :hint => "This will be your login." %>
  <%= f.input :age_less_than, :label => "* Age", :collection => [["Under 18",18],["18 - 20",21],["21+",99]], :hint => "Needed for opportunities with age restrictions" %>
  <%= f.input :password, :hint => "Passwords must be at least 8 characters." %>
  <%= f.input :password_confirmation, :label => "Confirm" %>
  <%= f.submit "Let's go!", :class => 'vendoredletsgo' %>
<% end %>
```

**Relevant script part:**

```
$('#container').on('click', 'a#sign_in_before_register_link, .sign_in_before_register a, a.sign_in_before_register', function(){
  $('#modal_signin').show();
  $('#modal_signin_portion').show();
  $('#modal_register_portion').hide();
  return false;
});

$('#container').on('click', 'a.signup_before_register_link', function(){
  $('#modal_signin').show();
  $('#modal_signin_portion').hide();
  $('#modal_register_portion').show();
  return false;
});
```

There are no errors in the error console in the browser. Also, watching the live logs, the information is passed to the correct url via a POST, but then spits out:

```
Started POST "/vid" for 71.198.92.173 at 2013-06-16 00:44:44 +0000
Processing by Volunteers::RegistrationsController#create as JS
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"O/rA1a6yJKW+as+u/47+5NOdW70Kk7mC0MsXYmTNF54=", "user"=>{"first_name"=>"Testy", "last_name"=>"test", "email"=>"testytest@website.com", "age_less_than"=>"99", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Let's go!"}
Redirected to https://website.com/vid
Completed 301 Moved Permanently in 1ms
```

Although it says it redirects, the actual page stays static, nothing changes. Conversely, on localhost, the logs then go through adding the user and sending out their welcome email just fine...100% of the time.

Any ideas why production would fail but localhost works just fine with the same code? I pushed again to make sure and restarted the server, still no luck.

Kevin

Comment: Are you trying to submit the form as JS, or as a standard POST?  I haven't tried redirecting from a JS post, I imagine you would need additional JS to capture the response and redirect accordingly.

Comment: Well, ideally, it should be submitted as a standard POST, right? It appears that it's going that at least to some degree. If that is the question - how do I submit it as a POST? Why does it work locally and not on production?

Comment: This part of the log: `#create as JS` indicates that the request was received as JSON.  It would simplify things and take out a lot of unknowns if it is submitted as a standard HTTP request.  Check in your form code for `remote: true`.  If that isn't there, check for any javascript that might be intercepting the form.

Comment: Ok, well now I've changed it to an HTML request....and it works...about 50% of the time. The other 50% of the time, it redirects to https://website.com/vid.

Comment: It is almost certainly something either in the controller action or one of the before_filters.  You'll need to step through each of those and find out where it could possibly be performing a redirect.